# Converting string hh-mm-ss format to time format hh:mm:ss in Presto

Tags: sql, datetime, presto, trino

In presto SQL, time is saved as a string like '17-00-00', '01-00-00', etc. I would like to convert that column into a time format (hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple replace should do the trick:

```sql
select replace('17-00-00', '-', ':');
```

Output:

```
  _col0
----------
 17:00:00
```

Or parsing:

```sql
select cast(date_parse('17-00-00', '%H-%i-%s') as time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here's where I landed:

```
 SELECT
  time_string,
  cast(substr(time_string, 1, 2) || ':' || substr(time_string, 4, 2) || ':' || substr(time_string, 7, 2) as time) as newtime_format
FROM table
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over simple replace?